# How dynamic allocation work on small architectures (with no MMU)

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I am working on a microcontroller (SHARC) this is a very standard microcontroller with an ALU, a DAG and some RAM. I would like to understand how `malloc` and `free` can work on these architectures.

Let's take an example. I have 16 blocks of free memory in my heap. I suppose the memory will look like this after running this code below:

```
ptr[0] = malloc(3); 
ptr[1] = malloc(5);
ptr[2] = malloc(7);
```

Heap:

```
0 - ptr0
1 |
2 |
3 - ptr1
4 |
5 |
6 |
7 |
8 - ptr2
9 |
A |
B |
C |
D | 
E |
F
```

Now we suppose I free `ptr[1]`. The available memory is 5 + 1 but I cannot do a `malloc` of 6 because the memory is fragmented.

So the solution I imagine is that at each malloc, malloc insert the address of the previous allocated bloc followed by the length of the reserved block. From this it can easily know the content of the heap and where it can find free space. In case of missing continous space, `malloc` cannot do the dynamic allocation.

I don't think a defragmentation can be possible without an MMU. Once `malloc` returned the address of a block, the running program will address this pointer and it cannot be changed on the fly.

In this case I see two possibilities:

1. The heap is very tiny and in this case `malloc` and `free` should never be used.
2. The heap is large, but the fragmented memory will never be defragmented until the reboot of the system.

Am I wrong and if so how does `malloc` and `free` work on small architectures like `8051`, `ARM Cortex M0`, `MSP430`, ...

Comment: MMU is for dealing with mappings between physical and virtual memory.  It has nothing directly to do with `malloc`/`free`.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. OTOH, one way that small systems avoid fragmentation is with [memory pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool).

Comment: I've also seen embedded systems where `free()` is implemented as a no-op and `malloc()` just increments a pointer into the “unallocated” memory region. I've also seen system with an implementation as `void *malloc() { return NULL; }`

Comment: It is completely dependent on the implementation in your standard C library. For very constrained scenarios, I think the best you can do is merging free blocks as soon as possible, at least that's what I came up with when implementing `malloc()` for *MS-DOS .COM* programs created by a 32bit compiler ([see here](https://github.com/Zirias/clang-libdos/blob/master/src/stdlib/stdlib_malloc.c))

Comment: I have used malloc()/free() on several very small architectures (16bit CPUs) .  They can be used, but it is far better to not use those functions in embedded systems unless their use is completely restricted to program startup/initialization, free() is never called and once past startup, malloc() is never called.   In most cases, the size of memory buffers is known and fixed, so even malloc() (which adds memory structure overhead and burns CPU cycles) can be skipped in favour of using buffer declarations like: `char myMem[20];`